# Unable to read the data from Excel file input

Tags: xls, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I was unable to read the Excel file from my pentaho ETL server repository. 
I get this error:

> unable to recognize OLE stream

What does that error mean?

Comment: Have you checked if the file is in the right format? ie. csv saved as xls.

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much @Adrian it worked. The xml page was saved as xls. SO, it's working now. Thanks alot

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

See the solution in comments.

The file contained an XML page that was saved as an .xls file. Converting this file solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

On double clicking the Microsoft Excel Input, change the Spread Sheet Type(Engine) as Excel 2007 instead of Excel 97-2003 which will be the default selected one, now you can add your excel file and the fields will be generated.

Comment: This mybe usefull but still does not answer the question `What does that error mean?` please provide more details about the fix you are proposing